# Problems defining and using types through QML files with QRC

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm having quite a bit of trouble defining new object types through QML documents and then trying to use those types. For context, I have a main.qml that uses the MyMenu to add MyMenu to a list of menu's. That part is working fine.

From there, I create a MyWindow component from MyMenu.qml, and in MyWindow.qml I try to use AutoTab.qml as a type so that I can break apart the tabs into individual files.

The problems I am running into seem to be related to the use of the QRC file. If I don't give MyWindow an alias, I get the error that the file is not found. If I give MyWindow an alias, I get the error that AutoTab is not a type.

**MyMenu.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Menu {
    id: m_MyMenu
    title: qsTr("Mine")
    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("MyWindow")
        onTriggered: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MyWindow");
            if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
                var obj = component.createObject(null)
                obj.visible = true
            }
            else {
                console.log(component.errorString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyWindow.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import myqml.controls 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 1024

    TekHorizontalTabView
    {
        id: m_horizontaltabview
        width: 1000
        height: 400

        AutoTab {}

        Tab {
            title: "ManualTab"
        }
    }
}
```

**AutoTab.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import myqml.controls 1.0

Tab {
    title: "AutoTab"
}
```

**qmlmain.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/main.qml</file>
        <file>qml/MyMenu.qml</file>
        <file alias="MyWindow">qml/MyWindow.qml</file>
        <file>qml/AutoTab.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: remove any aliases, just add it to resource as a regular file and try to replace `var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MyWindow");` with `var component = Qt.createComponent("MyWindow.qml");`. You should not specify `qrc:/` if all of the files in recources

Comment: I don't think that "You should not specify qrc:/ if all of the files in recources" is true. You can leave it out as long as the path is relative, as it will use the same URL scheme as the file it's referenced from. I don't think it hurts to leave it in though, as it will probably be added behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: 100% right on the fix, folibis.